# c++ vector assign() method fails frequently

Tags: c++, vector, thread-safety, assign

I have a vector of floats that is resized and emptied multiple times during the runtime using the assign() method, but it fails every time I switch to a smaller size throwing an exception `Vector subscript out of range`.

Declarations:

```
std::vector<float> buffer;
size_t size, c;
```

Setting size and deleting old content:

```
void SetBuffersize(size_t sz)
{
  // Resize vector
  // buffer.resize(sz); // really not needed?

  // Delete old content
  buffer.assign(sz, 0);
}
```

There's a thread running that continuously accesses this vector:

```
void Process()
{
  if (++c >= size) c = 0;
  float out = buffer[c];
  // do something with out;
}
```

And another thread can resize the buffer:

```
void ChangeStatus(int n)
{
  size = size_table[n];
  SetBuffersize(size);
}
```

I solved by adding a flag that blocked the `Process()` function while the vector is being resized. Is there a better solution to avoid the overhead of an extra `if` statement in a real-time thread?

Comment: *What* exception is being thrown?

Comment: Vector subscript out of range. As if assign() wrote past the end of the vector.

Comment: One solution that comes on top of my mind would be to estimate the max vector size that my program may use during the runtime and initialize the vector only once with a fixed size, then use the assign() method to empty its content without having to resize it every time, and only use the needed portion by storing the value of `size`. Less elegant but safer.

Comment: I think you need to include more specific code. Try to produce a minimal version that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is size always positive? Anyway: Did you know that resizing does not shrink the vector in memory?

Comment: `but it often fails`? how often? reproduce-able? is there another thread accessing the vector?

Comment: What value does `size` have? Negative sizes could be problematic. What compiler (and which version) do you use? [assign has change slightly since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign). Also consider removing the unnecessary call to `resize()` - assign should resize the vector anyways: `{ buffer.assign(size, 0); }`. And of course consider using the right type for `size`, i.e. an unsigned type like `std::size_t`.

Comment: Why won't you attach a debugger to see which statement raises the exception?

Comment: comment by vinod sahu: is (buffer) vector being used by multiple threads? Is there any case where you call SetBuffersize and simultaneously some other thread modifying buffer?

Comment: A negative value throws `std::length_error` on both gcc and clang, not out of range.

Comment: Size is always positive, I use indeed `size_t` even though my examples shows `long`, and I'm on C++11. It fails sistematically, is easily reproducible. At first I thought it was quite random, but then I have restricted my search to a specific part of the code where the vector is being used while it is resized. Comment by "vinod sahu" was indeed the answer to my problem: the exception was thrown because the vector was being accessed by another running thread while I was trying to resize it. I can fix it by using a flag that locks the other thread while resizing the vector.

Comment: Also, I didn't know that assign() would effectively resize() the vector at the same time. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you always have a race condition :

- Suppose size=10 and c=5
- `Process` evaluates the condition as false
- `ChangeStatus` clears the vector
- `Process` tries to get `buffer[c]` on a vector of size=0

You must take care when accessing data concurrently. What you need is a form of atomicity, take a look at semaphores, locks, etc. If you need performance you can look at spin locks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock